# MySQL trigger update other rows on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm trying to update the same table after an insert's trigger.
I know that you can't update the same table on a trigger but I can't seem to find an alternative.
I have for example the following table :

```
id   | team | time

1      A      1 568 725 200
2      A      1 568 725 200
3      B      1 568 824 950
```

If I update id 1 time from 1 568 725 200 to 1 568 455 800, id 2 time's should also be updated  to 1 568 455 800
because they are in the same team (A).
Is there a solution to achieve this update inside the trigger's transaction?
I'm working on a bad designed database and I can't change much.

Comment: Please share your existing update query. It should be possible to write a query that updates directly all concerned records.

Comment: 'Is there a solution to achieve this update inside the trigger's transaction' - no there isn't. IF you cannot update all team members in one update then you might consider wrapping both updates in a transaction outwith the trigger.

Comment: Use a stored procedure rather than a trigger.